# Reduce decimal places in CSV Column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

i'm very new to Python and Programming, so please explain it simple.
I want to write a code which can reduce the amount of decimal places in one column in the middle of a csv file. I know, that a lot of this code is wrong but i'm stuck so please help and explain me how to make it better.

```
import pandas as pd
 
File = pd.read_csv("D:files\Test2.csv",encoding = 'latin1',usecols = ["number"])
 
roundednumber = round (file, 10)

remaining = pd.read_csv("D:\file\Test2.csv",encoding = 'latin1',usecols = ["Name", "Age", "Location"])

Output = remaining, rounded number
Output.to_csv("D:\files\Test2Ausgabe.csv")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick for a column named ColumnName:

```
File['ColumnName'] = File['ColumnName'].round()
```

The above rounds to no decimal places. This will round to two decimal places:

```
File['ColumnName'] = File['ColumnName'].round(2)
```

In response to your comment below, asking how to round the column named 'Number' to 8 decimal places and assign it to the old data frame, you could do the following:

```
File['Number'] = File['Number'].round(8)
```

Comment: First Problem: i can only get 6 decimal places, I tried with 8 and 10 and its only working with 6 or below    Secound Problem: I don't know how to replace the old numbers with the new ones

Comment: My last edit should solve your second problem. I'm not sure I understand your first column. @Vinstand

Comment: I still don't get it. For example, i have these Columns: number,name,age,location. Then I round the Column number in order to get 8 decimal places. How can I write the new numbers into my old csv file with all the other Columns so i have one file with 4 Columns and my Number Column only has 8 decimal places?

Comment: @Vinstand Just changed my answer in response to your comments.

Comment: @Vinstand: your old CSV file will not be modified, unless you write your modified dataframe back to disk using `File.to_csv('yourfilename.csv')`. I would suggest to create a new file instead of overwriting your initial file, to avoid potentially loosing data.

Comment: Now i finally get it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Vinstand If I have answered your question please accept the answer. Thanks.